# Variable relationship properties in Neo4j

Tags: json, neo4j

I am constructing a graph in Neo4j like this. First, I create the nodes with an array property. Then I check if any two nodes have common elements between the arrays (using `apoc` intersection call) and if so I create a relationship between the nodes.

For example, lets say, nodes `N` and `M` has arrays `S = [A, B, C]` and `T = [A, B, D]` as properties, respectively, then `N` and `M` will have a relationship `r` between them, since they share the common elements `A, B`.

Now, each of the array elements also has properties associated with them and I want to populate the edge with common elements together with their properties. That is, we have `A.name, A.age, B.name, B.age` associated with them. Note that `A` and `B` are variables themselves. That is, `A` could be `Doctor X` and `B` could be `Doctor Y`.

How do I annotate the edges with the variable name and their properties so that I can query the database using the variable name? I somehow need to preserve the association between elements and their properties within the edges as edge properties.

How do I do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show us your queries? What you want to do is use the APOC library to create dynamic relationship types: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.relationship/

Comment: Thanks, I think this could work but need to see. Let me post the queries.